# Django - unable to handle form submission with dynamic field

Tags: python, django

In my Django form, I have one select field that needs to be populated dynamically based on some information about the current user. I am able to get the field set up correctly and rendered in the form - however, I'm getting an error when submitting the form because it's getting hung up on some of the logic that I have in the form's `__init__` method that only makes sense in the context of generating the form in the first place. I'm super-new to Django, and I'm not quite familiar with the design principles for this sort of situation.

In my app's `admin.py`, I have a method that's used for creating a custom view for a data export form - the relevant parts of it are set up like so...

```
# admin.py

from organizations.models import Organization
from .forms import ExportForm

class SomeModelAdmin(SimpleHistoryAdmin, SoftDeletionModelAdmin):

    def export_view(self, request):
        authorized_orgs_queryset = Organization.objects.viewable_for_user(request.user).all()
        authorized_orgs = [{'id': org.id, 'name': org.name} for org in authorized_orgs_queryset]

        context = dict(
           self.admin_site.each_context(request),
           form = ExportForm({'authorized_orgs': authorized_orgs}),
        )

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ExportForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                # do some stuff with the form.cleaned_data and return a .csv file as a response
                return response


       return TemplateResponse(request, 'export.html', context)
```

So the current user may be authorized to export data for multiple organizations, and in the form I'd like to present the user with a select element populated with these organizations.

The `ExportForm` has a number of "fixed" fields that are always the same, and just the one dynamic select element, which is populated by the `authorized_orgs` arg that I pass to it - it's defined as...

```
# forms.py

from django import forms

min_year = 1950
export_formats = [
    'csv',
    'xls',
    'xlsx',
    'ods',
    'json',
]

class ExportForm(forms.Form):
    current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year

    export_format = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, label='Format', choices=export_format_choices)
    apply_date_range = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    year_from = forms.IntegerField(required=False, disabled=True, min_value=min_year, max_value=current_year, initial=current_year)
    year_through = forms.IntegerField(required=False, disabled=True, min_value=min_year, max_value=current_year, initial=current_year)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExportForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        authorized_orgs_choices = [(org['id'], org['name']) for org in args[0]['authorized_orgs']]
        self.fields['authorized_org'] = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, label='Choose an authorized organization', choices=authorized_orgs_choices)
```

When I render the form, all is well. However, form submission is where things go awry. Submitting the form produces the error

```
File "/code/observations/forms.py", line 28, in __init__
  authorized_orgs_choices = [(org['id'], org['name']) for org in args[0]['authorized_orgs']]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 78, in __getitem__
  raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'authorized_orgs'
```

Now, I do understand why this is happening - the `__init__` is getting the values from the submitted form as its `args`, which are different from what I've supplied when setting up the form in the first place.

What I don't know is how this sort of thing should typically be handled in Django... how do I make it so that this dynamic field is created correctly when defining the form to be rendered, and that the data is available to me in `form.cleaned_data` when it's submitted?

Thanks very much for any insight and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha - found an answer here - [django forms post request raising an error on __init__ method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61104612/django-forms-post-request-raising-an-error-on-init-method)

I needed to make sure to pass those values again when handling the form's POST - I also reworked it a bit to make use of `kwargs` -

```
# admin.py

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ExportForm(request.POST, authorized_orgs=authorized_orgs)
```

```
# forms.py

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExportForm, self).__init__(*args)
        authorized_orgs_choices = [(org['id'], org['name']) for org in kwargs['authorized_orgs']]
        self.fields['authorized_org'] = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, label='Choose an authorized organization', choices=authorized_orgs_choices)
```